# How to install node_modules only one time for one React JS project?

Tags: jenkins, npm, node-modules

As I am implementing release automation of React JS project using Jenkins, it is required to download node_modules for a project only once and update successively. It doesn't mean one node_ modules for all projects. But one-time install for one project.

For example, Let's consider a project **LoginReactApp**.
I have to maintain a workspace like **D:/jenkins/workspace/LoginReactApp**.

So, I have to check out the source under **D:/jenkins/workspace/LoginReactApp/LoginReactApp**
and based on the package.json file, I need to download it under **D:/jenkins/workspace/LoginReactApp/**.

After the release process, the **LoginReactApp** project source will be deleted under **D:/jenkins/workspace/LoginReactApp/** and the node_modules folder will not be deleted.

So, next time it is enough to check out only **LoginReactApp** project source **D:/jenkins/workspace/LoginReactApp/** and it refers to already installed node_modules.

I have tried in command prompt below.

> D:/jenkins/workspace/LoginReactApp/LoginReactApp>npm install
> --production --f --prefix D:/jenkins/workspace/LoginReactApp/

Is it right? For next time it behaves differently.

How to install node_modules only one time for one React JS project?